CUDA Out of Memory Error with RTX 4060 When Training ResNet-18 on 128x128 Images
I am encountering a CUDA out-of-memory error while training a ResNet-18 model on 128x128 images using my RTX 4060 GPU. Despite reducing the batch size, I still face this issue. Below are the details of my setup and code:
Setup:

GPU: NVIDIA RTX 4060 with 8GB VRAM

Framework: PyTorch

Model: ResNet-18 (pre-trained)

Image Size: 128x128

Batch Size: 4 (initially tried 8, 16, 32)

Accumulation Steps: 8

Optimizer: Adam

Loss Function: CrossEntropyLoss

Windows: 11


import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.cuda.amp import GradScaler, autocast

# Define transformations
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((128, 128)),  # Reduce image size
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

# Load dataset
data_dir = 'OSA_16_07/OSA'
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=data_dir, transform=transform)

# Split the dataset into training and validation sets
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))  # 80% for training
val_size = len(dataset) - train_size  # 20% for validation
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])

# Create data loaders with smaller batch size
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)  # Reduced batch size
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=False)  # Reduced batch size

# Load pre-trained ResNet-18 model
model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

# Replace the final fully connected layer
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 11)

# Move the model to GPU if available
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = model.to(device)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Initialize GradScaler for mixed precision training
scaler = GradScaler()

# Training loop with gradient accumulation
num_epochs = 10
accumulation_steps = 8  # Number of steps to accumulate gradients
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        
        with autocast():
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels) / accumulation_steps
        
        scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        
        if (i + 1) % accumulation_steps == 0:
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        running_loss += loss.item() * accumulation_steps
    
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Training Loss: {running_loss/len(train_loader)}")
    
    # Validation step
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in val_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            
            with autocast():
                outputs = model(inputs)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            
            val_loss += loss.item()
            
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
    
    val_accuracy = 100 * correct / total
    print(f"Validation Loss: {val_loss/len(val_loader)}, Validation Accuracy: {val_accuracy}%")
    
    # Clear GPU cache
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

Steps Taken:

Reduced batch size to 4.

Cleared GPU cache using torch.cuda.empty_cache() after each epoch.

Verified no other processes are consuming GPU memory using nvidia-smi.


Questions:

Is it normal for an RTX 4060 with 8GB VRAM to encounter out-of-memory errors with this setup?

Are there any additional strategies I can use to manage GPU memory effectively?

Is my gradient accumulation implementation correct?


Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please, share code that are reproducible. I do not have the dataset on my laptop... I reproduced with torchvision.datasets.Flowers102 on my local machine with torch 2.3.1. Model takes about 230MB and batch size of 4 takes 260MB here. Running on a A4000. Plus, please provide your torch and torchvision used.
